# Is there a way to get specific information of yara rules on Python?

Tags: python, string-matching, malware-detection, yara

I need to create a database where I store yara rules, specifically i need data from meta section like the author, filetype and description (if they exist), also I need the name of the rule

I've been trying to look for any python module that could help, but I haven't find anything so far, I read the oficial yara documentation for python, but there aren't any method that provides that information, so I was wondering if there's any python module or algorithm that can help me with this task, I've been thinking about creating a lexical analyzer and a parser but it's too complicated

Comment: Not only is StackOverflow not the place to ask for recommendations for libraries, frameworks, etc. but it's also entirely unclear from your question what exactly you need a solution for. You're asking for "a way to get specific information of yara rules" - do you mean that you're simply looking for a Python interface to use Yara? E.g. https://yara.readthedocs.io/en/latest/yarapython.html ?